# How to get distinct values from an Array of Classes?

Tags: swift, xcode

I've found many examples on how to get the distinct values from an array such as this:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

And then I can do `Array(Set(myArray))`, however, this doesn't work when the array value is a class.

However, what I need is to get a list of distinct values from a property of a class that is in an array such as this class:

```
class Alert: Decodable {
    var id: Int?

    var category: String?
    var category_id: Int?

    var summary: String?
    var title: String?
    var publish_date: String?

}
```

I'd like to get a list of "category" from my array.

I know I can probably just loop through the array, and append a new array if the value doesn't exist. Not sure if this is the most effective way, or if there is a more swifty way of doing things.

I found I can do:

```
let categories = self.items!.map { $0.category }
```

Which will get a list of the categories, but not sure how to make them distinct. I tried `Array(Set(`, but that doesn't work. I get the following error:

> Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred

I'm relatively new to swift, so I know what I want to do, just can't figure it out syntactically.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Set` requires your elements to be `Hashable`. That means they have to be `Equatable` and provide a hashing value.

If your aim is to create list of unique categories, then you should start by creating an array of categories:

```
let categories = (self.items ?? []).compactMap { $0.category }
```

Then you can simply get unique categories using `Set`:

```
let uniqueCategories = Array(Set(categories))
```

However, note that `Set` does not keep items ordered. If you also need to keep the `categories` in order then I would recommend a simple `Array` extension:

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func distinct() -> Array<Element> {
        var set = Set<Element>()
        return filter {
            guard !set.contains($0) else { return false }
            set.insert($0)
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

or simplified using `Set.insert` return value ([Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus)'s idea):

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func distinct() -> Array<Element> {
        var set = Set<Element>()
        return filter { set.insert($0).inserted }
    }
}
```

and then

```
let uniqueCategories = (self.items ?? [])
   .flatMap { $0.category }
   .distinct()
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thank you for the detailed response. It's far better than what I found :)

Comment: why not simply  `return filter { set.insert($0).inserted }` or using flatMap instead of filter `return flatMap { set.insert($0).inserted ? $0 : nil }`

Comment: @LeoDabus Using `flatMap` instead of `filter` doesn't seem like a good idea. To be honest, I didn't know that `Set.insert` has a return value. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer I was looking for. If I extract the categories like this:

```
let categories = self.items!.map({ (alert: Alert) -> String in
    alert.category!
})
```

I can then get the distinct list:

```
print(Array(Set(categories)))
```

It will work.

This might not be the best way of doing it, but I'm posting this as an answer until someone posts one that is better.